# Camunda Tomcat max file size exceeded

Tags: tomcat, camunda

I use the camunda (tomcat included) version. When i try to upload large files using the auto-generated form it just freezes and i cant complete the task. In the browser console i saw

```
Error: Maximum file size of 5.00 MB exceeded.
    transformFiles http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:1
    submit http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:1
    link http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/scripts/camunda-tasklist-ui.js?bust=7.17.0:41
    complete http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/scripts/camunda-tasklist-ui.js?bust=7.17.0:41
    fn http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0 line 36 > Function:4
    i http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:36
    $eval http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:36
    $apply http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:36
    compile http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:36
    dispatch http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:120
    handle http://localhost:8080/camunda/lib/deps.js?bust=7.17.0:120
```

so i searched on the web how to increase the max file size. I found [this one](https://tecadmin.net/increase-tomcat-upload-file-size-limit/) but in my config it says it is actually configured for files up to 50MB. Of course i restarted the tomcat server!

Why does my browser say 5MB exceeded?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the auto-generated forms limit the size to 5MB, independent of the limit configured in Tomcat. If you switch to an (embedded) custom from, you can control the file size as shown here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/forms/embedded-forms/controls/files/

However, consider a system design where large files get stored in a dedicated system (DMS, S3 bucket, etc) and the process instance carries only a reference to the file. Storing large binaries in the audit trail database does not scale so well.

Comment: Hi and thank you, i also found that page but i dont know where i should put that file. In the modeler i can add additional files in the deploy menu, when i try to add a html form i get an error message. Maybe i just wrote it bad?

Comment: When i click "open in external form" i ended up at "localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/default/<form-name>?taskId=..." on a "404 Not found" page

Comment: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/forms/embedded-forms/